# how to populate a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I was trying to write a code that needs to be outputted as matrix but since being a novice, i am not getting it right. Basically i want to generate a matrix of counts for each of A,C,G,T for each column. I was able to do it for a single column but having hard time to do it for other columns.

Input file

```
>Rosalind_1
ATCCAGCT
>Rosalind_2
GGGCAACT
>Rosalind_3
ATGGATCT
>Rosalind_4
AAGCAACC
>Rosalind_5
TTGGAACT
>Rosalind_6
ATGCCATT
>Rosalind_7
ATGGCACT
```

My code so far

```
fh_in = open("consensus_seq.txt", 'r')

A_count = 0
C_count = 0
G_count = 0
T_count = 0

result = []
for line in fh_in:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith(">"):
        for nuc in line[0]:
            if nuc == "A":
                A_count += 1
            if nuc == "C":
                C_count += 1
            if nuc == "G":
                G_count += 1
            if nuc == "T":
                T_count += 1
result.append(A_count)
result.append(C_count)
result.append(G_count)
result.append(T_count)
print result
```

Output

```
[5, 0, 1, 1]
```

The actual output that i want is

```
A   5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0
C   0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1
G   1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
T   1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
```

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy` to load the text file. Since the format is a little funky it is hard to load, but the summation becomes trivial after that:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("raw.txt", comments=">", 
                  converters = {0: lambda s: [x for x in s]}, dtype=str)

print (data=="A").sum(axis=0)
print (data=="T").sum(axis=0)
print (data=="C").sum(axis=0)
print (data=="G").sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0]
[1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6]
[0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1]
[1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0]
```

The real advantage to this is the numpy array you've constructed can do other things. For example, let's say I wanted to know, instead of the sum, the average number of times we found an `A` along the columns of the "Rosalinds":

```
print (data=="A").mean(axis=0)
[ 0.71428571  0.14285714  0.  0.  0.71428571  0.71428571 0.   0.]
```

Answer (score 3):

First make a list of the rows, stripping out the lines starting with >. Then you can `zip` this to turn it into a list of columns. Then you can make a list of column counts of each letter.

```
rows = [line.strip() for line in infile if not line.startswith('>')]
columns = zip(*rows)
for letter in 'ACGT':
    print letter, [column.count(letter) for column in columns]
```

However this may be memory intensive if your file is very large. An alternative is just to go through line by line counting the letters.

```
counts = {letter: [0] * 8 for letter in 'ACGT'}
for line in infile:
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        for i, letter in enumerate(line.strip()):
            counts[letter][i] += 1
for letter, columns in counts.items():
    print letter, columns
```

You could also use a `Counter`, especially if you aren't sure in advance how many columns there will be:

```
from collections import Counter
# ...
counts = Counter()
for line in infile:
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        counts.update(enumerate(line.strip()))

columns = range(max(counts.keys())[0])
for letter in 'ACGT':
    print letter, [counts[column, letter] for column in columns]
```

Comment: +1 . i know about zip, but tell me about this `zip(*rows)`, what * represent here??

Comment: * unpacks an argument list https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists. In this case it sends the first row to zip as its first argument, the second row as the 2nd argument, etc.

Comment: what if the number of columns is not 8? Is there a way to insert `len` function in the counts list?

Comment: About your comment on memory, `from itertools import izip` should take care of that issue.  From your answer I learned the `.count()` method, very good!

Comment: My pet issue, formatting. Use `print letter,"", "".join["%2d"%(column.count(letter),) for column in columns]` to get exactly the example output of the OP.

Comment: @gboffi izip won't make much difference in this case as you still need to load all of the rows into memory before you can count the letters in each column (if using the `.count()` method)

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
answer = []
with open('blah') as infile:
  rows = [line.strip() for _,line in zip(infile, infile)]
  cols = zip(*rows)
  for col in cols:
    d = collections.Counter(col)
    answer.append([d[i] for i in "ATCG"])
    answer = [list(i) for i in zip(*answer)]
for line in answer:
  print(' '.join([str(i) for i in line]))
```

Output:

```
5 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 6 6
5 0 2 0 1
0 1 6 0 0
```